# How to annotate a function that's a property in an object?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I've got the following type alias:

```
type TestType = {
  critical: string,
  failProps: Object,
  successProps: ?Object,
  test: Function,
};
```

I'd like to be more specific with `test`. The function should be of this signature:

```
function (value: string): boolean { /* ... */ }
```

How do I indicate that `test` should take a single string argument and return a boolean?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following syntax:

```
type TestType = {
  critical: string,
  failProps: Object,
  successProps: ?Object,
  test: (value: string) => boolean,
};
```

...or if you want to reuse the function type somewhere else:

```
type functionType = (value: string) => boolean
type TestType = {
  critical: string,
  failProps: Object,
  successProps: ?Object,
  test: functionType,
};
```